# Convert to string using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to print a value to string format.

```
Rails.logger.debug(request)
```

while am trying to print am getting the output as

```
#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x45aa2c8>
```

How can i print this value to string form.

Comment: Use `to_s` or `inspect`

Comment: Rails.logger.debug(request.inspect)???

Comment: you probably want .body() to get the content of the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.inspect` the object to output its contents, but keep in mind this object is a class that contains more than just one string. If there is a specific piece of data you are after please add that to your question.

```
Rails.logger.debug(request.inspect)
```

[ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) documentation - look here for individual instance methods that may contain the information you're after.

Comment: is there any ways to convert these string to json

Comment: http://flori.github.io/json/doc/classes/JSON.html#method-i-pretty_generate may help you do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will return you the correct result.

Rails.logger.info(request)

What you have written, that normally returns an array.